# How to implement generic methods in java 8

Tags: generics, design-patterns, java-8

I want to write the following similar methods.

method1:

```
public void method1(A a){
 //do some thing
}
```

method2:

```
public C method2(B b){
 //do some thing
}
```

method3:

```
public D method3(E b){
 //do some thing
}
```

the processing logic of the three interfaces method1, method2, and method3 is the same. I would like to ask whether these three methods can be abstracted by generic methods or design patterns.